# Integration of mixture distribution

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, normal-distribution, bayesian

Suppose $y | \mu \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, $\mu \sim w\delta_0 + (1-w)N(m_0, s_0^2)$, where $\delta_0$ is [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)(In bayesian statistics, this mixture is called spike and slab). Now I want to find distribution of $y$.
My solution is
$f(y) = \int p(y|\mu) p(\mu) d\mu = w * N(y|0, \sigma^2) + (1-w)*\int N(y|\mu, \sigma^2) * N(\mu | m_0, s_0^2) d\mu$.
Am I right?

Comment: I'd write  $f(y) = w * N(0, \sigma^2) + (1-w)*\int N(\mu, \sigma^2) * N(m_0, s_0) d\mu$.

Comment: It is slightly confusing to use $\sigma^2$ and $s_0$ to each represent variances.  Did you intend $s_0^2$?